# Warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size (char* = function())

Tags: c

I am trying to find a way to store the return value of this function...

```
int createDirectory() {
 int buffer = 21;            //variable holds buffer count
 int pid = getpid();         //variable calls builtin C function to get process id

 char* directory = malloc(buffer * sizeof(char));  //dynamically creates array of chars
 char* prefix = "schmcory.rooms." ;    //prefix is set to my user id and rooms

 //counts characters and stores in buffer
 snprintf(directory, buffer, "%s%d", prefix, pid);
 //printf("%s\n", directory); //for testing purposes

 struct stat st = {0};   //initialize system struct

 //if statement checks if directory exists
 if(stat(directory, &st) == -1) {
  mkdir(directory, 0755);  //creates directory 
 }

 free(directory);                 //free dynamically allocated memory
 return *directory; 
}
```

...into this variable char* directory = createDirectory();

I am getting the below error: 
cast to pointer from integer of different size

I have tried the following:

```
char* directory = (void*)createDirectory(); 
char* directory = (int)createDirectory(); 
char directory = createDirectory(); //compiles w/o warning but prints nothing
```

I am trying to print the results in my main function.

```
printf(directory);
```

Comment: None of this code makes any sense. Every single line has an error. if not only a semantic one. The function should return `char *` instead of `int` and **what good would `free`ing do to the path name... By the way, which C book are you reading?

Comment: No offense intended here, but that's impossible. The function behaves exactly as I want it to.

Comment: No offense intended here but clearly it doesn't.

Comment: Two hints: return types. You can’t free memory you want to return.

Comment: Antti, it does. When the function is simply called createDirectory() in main, it creates a directory when I compile on the command line.

Comment: Yes it creates a directory. That's the one thing it does right, except that of course it might not (`mkdir` could return an error).

Comment: In the future please don't just throw casts here and there, but try and think what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issue with the code :

1. return value of the function is char * not int - `char * createDirectory();`
2. you do free before you return the pointer
   here is the code working (Linux environment)

   ```
            //free(directory);                 
            return directory; 
           }
           int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
           {
               char* directory = createDirectory();
                printf ("main says %s \n", directory);
               free(directory);
           }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to return the result of `mkdir`, not the string containing the path, switch to

```
int ret = -1;

if (stat(directory, &st) != -1)       // Notice `!=` instead of `==`
{
    ret = mkdir(directory, 0755);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        perror("mkdir")
    }
}
free(directory);
return ret;
```

and the caller should do something like:

```
int dir;

if ((dir = createDirectory()) != -1)
{
    ... do your stuff with dir
}
else
{
    ... raise exception
}
```

EDIT:

It seems that you want to return something like: `schmcory.rooms.49111`

In this case, the prototype should be

```
char *createDirectory(void) {     // Return a pointer to `char`
```

instead of

```
int createDirectory() {
```

But do not call `free` or you end up deleting the result:

```
free(directory);    // Remove this line
```

and

```
return *directory;
```

should be

```
return directory; // Do not dereference, you don't want the first char, you want the whole string
```

Comment: How can you understand correctly? I understand that they want the path being returned. How else would you find out its name to be printed in the `main()` function

Comment: @AnttiHaapala then why return an `int`, and why call `free` with the string containing the result?

Comment: I wait for a clarification before deleting the answer ;)

Comment: That's your right. You can request clarifications from the OP by writing a comment under their post ;-)

Comment: David, yes. I am looking to return the result of mkdir. Am I not doing that correctly? It does create a directory when simply called in main and not when Im trying to store it in a variable.

Comment: @CoryAllen, but the return of mkdir as strng containing the path i.e. `/home/Cory`?  or the identifier of the diretctory given by the system. i.e 47678?

Comment: Not the whole path, no. I am looking to return just this... "schmcory.rooms.pid, ex: schmcory.rooms.49111"

Comment: His post where he was rude got deleted by the mods.